# Good Game Engine for Teaching Purposes

Tags: 3d, game-engine

I am teaching 3D Computer Graphics.
I have to give some lesson on a game engine, but I do not know any game engine.After searching on google, I found a lot of free and open source Game Engine, developed in C# or Java.
What I need is a game engine include Physics , Sound and AI APIs; and is easy to learn ,free and has a good documentation and tutorials.

Can anyone suggest a good game engine which suits my requirements?

Comment: You have to teach a course, but you know nothing about the subject. How does that work?

Comment: I was teaching openGL only.but now I want to give some lessons about game engine for the next semester. so I'll start learing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), though it's actually not a game engine(it's a graphics engine):

> OGRE (Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine) is a scene-oriented, flexible 3D engine written in C++ designed to make it easier and more intuitive for developers to produce applications utilising hardware-accelerated 3D graphics. The class library abstracts all the details of using the underlying system libraries like Direct3D and OpenGL and provides an interface based on world objects and other intuitive classes.

And for the functions like physics, sound, there're some plugins exist. E.g:

- **Physics**: [Bullet Physics](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/) (and there's a [OgreBullet](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreBullet) wrapper, which allows you to easily integrate Bullet Physics Engine into your project)
- **Sound**: [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/OpenAL%20Wiki/Source%20Code.aspx) is cool (and there's a [OgreAL](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewforum.php?f=10) bindings to it).
- **UI**: [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is better than Ogre3D's own UI lib.

And there're many addons [HERE](http://www.ogre3d.org/developers/addons).

[Wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/), [manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/), [forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/), even [books](http://www.ogre3d.org/documentation/books), you can get that you like!

What's more, it's free and open source(MIT license). ;)

Answer (score 2):

The most 3d engines are pure graphics engines. Like Irrlicht, jMonkeyEngine or OGRE. Of course you can plug some physics engine, like Bullet, PhysX or ODE.

> What I need is a game engine include Physics , Sound and AI APIs;

You could use UDK with UnrealScript.
Or Torque Game Engine with TorqueScript.
Or CryEngine.

Comment: @aladein I'd recommend torque also, but it isn't free.  Regardless of your engine of choice, there will probably be a pretty steep learning curve for your class.  Graphics, physics, sound, and AI are all big domains.  So, it would seem very challenging to produce an API that gives you much power while remaining simple and easy to learn (as you must know from teaching OpenGL).

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D is a cross platform game engine who's scripts are done in mono C#.
I would highly recommend you show that in your lessen, as its a viable tool for anyone interested in games.

http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Microsoft's XNA. You and your students call all download Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone (which includes XNA for PC and XBOX), legally, for free. Although, if you are in an academic institution and you all have academic email addresses, you can also sign up for Dreamspark and get Visual Studio Professional, but for educational purposes only.

You can get a free ebook from Microsoft on XNA on the Windows Phone 7 platform which also covers this on PC and XBOX from here:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html

Also, the Microsoft website is full of basic tutorials to help you get started such as this one:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I studied 3D gaming design a few years ago and Irrlicht is one of the easiest to start with. It uses C++ and thus allowing students to easily get IDEs to start assignments and projects.

If your school is linked with Microsoft MSDNAA, it would be even better since Visual Studios will be free for your students.

Answer (score 0):

There are **no** game engines that have *physics module*, *sound module* and *AI module* and are *well documented* and *free* and *easy to learn*.
The ones closest to your request:

- Unity3D

Good stability, physics, 3D, sound, no AI. But this one definately is not free.

- Ogre3D

Free, stable, physics, sound module.

Pls read [gamesparks](https://www.gamesparks.com/blog/game-engine-analysis-and-comparison/).